# openMp and the number of cores vs cpus

Tags: linux, multithreading, openmp, cpu-cores

I'm wondering about how openmp figures out how many threads it can run via the `omp_get_max_threads()` library call.  I'm running on a centOS linux machine using gcc -fopenmp.  My machine has 16 **AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 6136 CPU**s, each with 8 cores, all according to /proc/cpuinfo.  If I run omp_get_num_procs() it returns 16.  But `omp_get_max_threads()` also returns 16.  Why isn't the max threads number 16*8?

When I run a program that uses 16 threads I see the program in `top` running at ~1600% of CPU and if I toggle 'Last used cpu (SMP)' that number moves around a bit.  So the 1600% makes sense but is there any way to know which cores of which CPUs the threads are running on?

I'm pretty new to openmp so sorry if these questions seem naive.

Comment: your thread may migrate from cpu to cpu, thus this not a constant value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the *hwloc* tool set to know the binding of the threads of any application to the hardware threads/cores. You need only the name or the PID of the target running process. Here is an example:

```
$ hwloc-ps --pid 2038168 --threads --get-last-cpu-location
2038168 Machine:0       ./a.out
 2038168    Core:5      a.out
 2038169    Core:3      a.out
 2038170    Core:1      a.out
 2038171    Core:4      a.out
 2038172    Core:0      a.out
 2038173    Core:2      a.out
```

Here we can see that the process a.out (with the PID 2038168) uses 6 threads each map on different cores.
However, the mapping of threads on cores over time can change if you do not configure OpenMP properly (a starting point is to set the environment variables [OMP_PROC_BIND](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpse52.html) and [OMP_PLACES](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpse53.html)).

Additionally, you can use  `hwloc-ps` to understand the topology of your machine (how many cores there are, how many threads, how they are connected, etc.).
I am very surprise you can have 16 "AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 6136 CPUs". Indeed, [this processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_Opteron_microprocessors) use the [G34 socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket_G34) which is available in up to 4-socket arrangements (and 8 dies). So, please check this with `hwloc-ps`!

An alternative way is to use a *profiling tool* (such as Intel VTune).

Comment: thanks so much for the information.  Very helpful!  And yes, I was misinterpreting the information in /proc/cpuinfo.  It lists 16 processor entries and each processor block has the entry `cpu cores : 8`.  I didn't realize that the processors are logical entries.  The fact that the `cpu cores` entry gets repeated in every block is a bit confusing but then it was the only way I could calculate the number of physical CPUs from the file info: 16 processors/8 cores per CPU = 2 AMD 6136 CPUs.